# NestWhileList stop criteria for second appearecnce of element

Tags: list-manipulation, iteration

How i can stop evaluation of NestWhileList after second zero occurs?

In my variant it stops at the first step.

```
NestWhileList[# + RandomChoice[{1, -1}] &, 0, # != 0 &]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about

```
go := NestWhileList[#+RandomChoice[{1,-1}]&,0,#!=0&,{2,1}]
```

Examples:

```
SeedRandom[1];
go
(* {0,-1,-2,-1,-2,-1,0} *)
```

and

```
SeedRandom[25];
ListLinePlot[go]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. What means {2,1} here?

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NestWhileList.html) under "Details", {2,1} means that it only starts applying the test after at least 2 results have been generated, and then it supplies 1 result to test at a time.